# converting a dvi to pdf without showing it in the web page in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is jsPDF function to create a PDF.Problem is that the div I want to convert to a pdf should not visible in the web page.If I use 'hidden' in the div it will ouput a blank pdf

```
 function generatePDF(){
        var rep = new jsPDF("p","pt","a4")
        rep.html(document.querySelector("#rep1"),{
            callback: function(pdf){
                pdf.save("report.pdf");   
            }
        })
    }
```

this is the div I want to convert to PDF.

```
<div id="rep1">content<div>
```

Comment: If you have things in the DOM that shouldn't be visible, just set their root element CSS (or wrapping element CSS) to `display: none`?

Comment: then pdf is also blank

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this, like when you click on the button then you can show the block and hide it after print

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

export default function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("none");

  const generatePDF = () => {
    setDisplay("block");
    var rep = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
    rep.html(document.querySelector("#rep1"), {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save("report.pdf");
        setDisplay("none");
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="rep1" style={{ display }}>
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </div>
      <button onClick={generatePDF}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-worker-l32io?file=/src/App.js

Code View: https://l32io.csb.app/

Comment: Sorry but I cant let it show for one time

Comment: Ok, make the parent hidden and you childs will show, please check the updated codesadnbox